# How to use an existing .NET 4.0 app with Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have a functional .NET WinForms app that uses all the latest features of .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0, such as reflection, dynamic code generation (CIL), extensions, user components, etc. Is it easy to run this app on Mono? I currently want to see it fully functional on Windows 7, and if all is well then I'll try running it on Unix. Is this easily possible or do I have a large "porting" job ahead?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility http://go-mono.com/status/

Comment: try to `xbuild projectname.csproj` and see what happen!, you will need to install mono complete in order to do it, I think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just copy the .exe and .dll files over to the Linux box, and run the app:

```
mono yourapp.exe
```

I recommend you mono 3.x, not older.

Most glitches you find will most probably have to do with path assumptions (like using "\" to concatenate paths instead of using Path.Combine). A workaround for this is to use an environment variable defined here: http://www.mono-project.com/IOMap

Answer (score -2):

Everything except UI should run fine on Mono. On MonoTouch however, the code is statically linked so certain reflection features are unavailable (like emitting code and virtual generic methods).

Comment: it's a winForms app, where did he talk about iPhones/iPads??

Comment: It's a concern when writing cross-platform .NET/Mono code. Xamarin.Mac now offers a linker with similar restrictions.

Comment: Xamarin.Mac is for writing Mac apps with Mono, with Cocoa API and all that. WinForms can run on Mac/Linux. Cocoa cannot run in Linux/Windows.

Comment: You're confused. If you're writing cross-platform code then you need to appeal to to the subset of features that works across all the platforms. For example, I wrote a common utility library that is used in MVC 3 apps, WinForms apps, WPF apps, iPhone monotouch apps, windows mobile apps. I've had to avoid certain features so that it runs in all platforms (like virtual generic methods).

Comment: You seem to be talking about the Mac AppStore requirements of your app being self-contained. Yes, for that, your app must run without requiring dependencies (embedding Mono runtime) and avoiding dynamic code. But the OP doesn't mention anything about app stores, it just asks about running a .NET app with Mono.